# What are all the steps I have to do to get my bootstrap email form working?

Tags: form-submit, forms, contact-form, bootstrap-form-helper

What should I do to get my form working? My website and everything is set up. I just can't get my form working. Can I do it from rdp? or firezila server?

```
    <form>
       <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
 <div class="form-group">
  <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="3"  placeholder="Message"></textarea>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Request</button>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>    
 </form>
```

Comment: You should have some php, asp.net or javascript code, can I see that?

Comment: I may give the answer in php if you want plz reply then! PHP surely works with firezila.

Answer (score 0):

Submit your form to php and send the mail, ulter the code as below and consider adding a subject field too:

```
<form name="nameforform" action="thephpfilename.php" method="POST">
       <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name" name="name">
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address" name="email">
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
 <div class="form-group">
  <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="3"  placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Request</button>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>    
 </form>
```

Then create a php file (eg: thefilename.php) [besure to change the action attribute of the form element to that of the created php file's name.

The php file should have the following code:

```
<?php
$to      = $_POST['email'];
$subject = '';
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = 'From:'. $_POST['name'] . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

It would work, be sure to tweak your server's settings and also specify more info in the question next time.

Lastly how it works,

> **On submitting the form the browser sends a get/post request to the file specified on the action attribute of the form element. The php
>   file handles the request and does the needy. The data is stored with
>   reference to the name attribute of the input and textarea elements.
>   The data can be stored as arrays too. Here we use the php's `mail()`
>   function to send the mail using appropriate headers. HTML or bootstrap
>   cannot send mail independently without server intervention.**

Be sure to comment for more info and other help, enjoy out there.

Comment: Man, I did it but, it didn't work out for me. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. What can I provide to you so, you can help me to the best of your ability?

Comment: first of all what is it that you want I mean is this part of a mailing site like gmail where people can send emails to one another or a feedback reciver or any other please reply what you want to do, mail to whom! @M.Huerta . Also give me your code that you tried (code you modified from what I posted) , the file list of your '/' root directory (Also called the WWW directory where your files are in)